# Git: How to ignore files for a specific remote?

Tags: git, gitignore

For instance, if there are two `origin`s for a repo:

```bash
cd my-repo
git remote add origin https://example.com/shared/repo.git
git remote add origin-private https://example.com/private/repo.git
```

and there are two configuration files under the dir `my-repo`, named `public.template.env` and `John.env`.

Now, if we need to ensure: the first one is ok to publish to both origins, while the 2nd one should be pushed to the `origin-private` only.

Is there a way to do that ?

It seems [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002158/git-ignoring-files-based-on-remote) is very close to the setting here, after some Googlings. However, it suggest there is no way to do that with Git. But it is a old post, wondering if there are changes about it.

Comment: "ignoring" is a _working tree_-only operation which affects the way `git add` behaves... it can't affect a _remote_ as remotes just hold whatever you put in commits.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when you ignore files with `.gitignore`, that tells Git not to commit those files if they appear in the working tree and don't already appear in the index (unless you force the operation).  Once a file is committed, it's in the history.

In order to push a history without that file, you'd have to have a separate history without that file, which would mean that the two histories would completely diverge and wouldn't share any commits in common, except for the commits before that file was created.  There's no way to push only the same history without that file, because the remote side would detect that you hadn't sent that file and the history would be corrupt.

Thus, what you want to do is functionally very difficult because it involves keeping two completely different histories in the same repository, and as a practical matter people don't do it for that reason.  If you want, you can create a submodule of a private repository containing some private files, and publish the public one, while not publishing the private one.  People would the know that there were private files, but wouldn't be able to access them.